# What property is used to assign a default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm pretty sure that there's a property associated with textboxes or dropdown lists, in ASP.NET WebForms, that can substitute a null if the user enters something else. For example we've got users entering "9999" into a field. I'd rather assign a null if the user enters a "9999". Am I correct about that? Or I know that there's an event that can be used to do some processing before submitting the POST to the server. But if there's a property I'd rather just use that.

Comment: This question is all over the place.  If I understand you, you want a property that will replace a user inputted value of 9999 with null when you post.  There is no property that will do this.  As for events to handle data before its posted, use the On Client Click to your button and write javascript for it.

Comment: What is the goal? Validation? And instead of stopping them, change the value to a default?

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868250/how-can-i-dynamically-clear-all-controls-in-a-user-control

Comment: After learning more of what is actually happening, I found out that the issue is more with a SSIS package truncating the data to "9999" when it should be "999999", as it is stored in the database. I was misinformed about the problem. Thank you everyone for your answers, they will probably be useful to me in the future.